# Exception while instantiating RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

Am using Rest Template to consume web services in a Maven project and packaged the project to jar to add as a dependency to my other web application
but throwing Exception to console at instantiating the RestTemplate even though i put the code to catch the exception, its directly throwing the below Exception to console. can anyone know the reason?

```
try{
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); //getting the Exception here
}
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace(); // but its not coming here 
}
```

the dependenices i have added in my pom.xml file :

```
<!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON-Binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

the Exception at server side is :

```
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:86)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:63)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.create(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:807)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:585)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include the correct version jackson-databind jar file in classpath. The servlet container has not started to hit your code base.

Comment: i have tried by giving 2.8.7 version for jackson-databind still its not working... can you suggest which version need to be added? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide all the below dependencies in your pom.xml with same version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This should help.